# Browse button in StringProperty FILE_PATH not working

Tags: python, properties, path

I'm using `context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)` to show a property dialog. One of the things I need is an export directory, so I added:

`exportPath = StringProperty(name="Path", subtype='FILE_PATH')` to the class.

The property does show up, and there is a button to click on as it should, but when I click on that button, nothing happens. Do I need to do something additional to make this work, or is this a bug?

Thanks!

Comment: BramVaessen, -- maybe stick around to see if someone can back up my assertion. I do believe it to be true but can't point to an explicit mention of it in the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't open the File / Directory view when the `invoke_props_dialog` itself is open, it's a blocking dialogue. I think this is mentioned in the documentation. (i'll try to find it and link here)

Comment: I spent almost a day to find this... Thank you.